# How do you send data to the Detail View from Master View in iOS 5 iPad app?

Tags: arrays, ios5, uisplitviewcontroller, detailview

I am trying to make an extremely simple app that using a split view.  I would like a list of checklists on the left that you can click on and display more detailed information on the right side of the screen.  It seems that split view is the right view controller but I am having some trouble.  I am very new to iOS programming.  I understand how to add items to the Master View on the left using the inspector options.  I am not using arrays to populate my cells in Master View.  I simply added more cells through inspector and just renamed the label of each.  I do not however understand how to connect each cell with the Detail View.  I have searched far and wide on the internet and come up with nothing.  All information is outdated and doesn't work for Xcode 4.2 or iOS 5.  If you have any information at all please help.  I am a total noob with this so please be as descriptive and basic as possible.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Look at the MultipleDetailsViews.xcodeproj provided by Apple. It supports iOS 5 and also runs fine on iOS 6.